# Simple python web server?

Tags: python

My project is telemedecine that means i have to create a web server and get values from my sensors and affiche them into web page

So , I ask any ideas to make a simple web server ?

my scripts maked with python so i think the webserver should be with python ?

Any simple tutorial please ?

Comment: Welcome -- but this is not really [a pi-specific question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) since python and web servers are not unique to the hardware.   General programming questions belong on our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) (where there are currently 600+ K [questions tagged "python"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), more than 40x our total volume).

Comment: A few quick pointers though: 1) Technically you do not need a python web server to run/control a python script/process, although it is not a bad idea to integrate them if that is the primary purpose of the server; 2) Web services in python are generally implemented using [frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework) such as *django* or *flask*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using only the socket module, below is a web server with a lot of comments to help you understand what is happening:

```
import socket #imports a module named "socket"

HOST, PORT = '', 80 #defines the host as blank, which tells the server to listen on all possible ips, and defines the port as 80

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)# creates the socket
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
#SO_REUSEADDR mainly changes how wildcard addresses are treated when searching for conflicts. Without SO_REUSEADDR, binding socketA to 0.0.0.0:21 and then binding socketB to 192.168.0.1:21 will fail (with error EADDRINUSE),
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT)) #tells the socket which ip's and port to listen to
listen_socket.listen(1) #indicates the number of servers to create
while True: #creates an infinite loop
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept() #tells the server to accept any incoming connections
    request = client_connection.recv(1024) #proccesses the incoming data into a string
    print request #prints that string

    http_response = """\
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

mohammad made this
"""
    client_connection.sendall(http_response) #returns a string of data to the client
    client_connection.close() # closes the clients connection
```

Comment: thanks for the idea , but i  need a web page that show my sensors values with some designs .

Comment: @RouiniHo you did not indicate how the values are being passed to the web server and what do you mean by designs? this was not part of the initial question

Comment: yes im sorry , i dont know yet how the values will be passed to the web server . i find some solutions with cgi but i dont know yet if its the simple solution

Comment: @RouiniHo are your values simply strings?

Comment: my values are simple numbers variable from sensor

Comment: @RouiniHo if all you want is a basic webpage adding `http_response=http_response+' sensor 1: '+str(sensorValue)` should work fine, now please mark this answer as the correct one, by clicking the checkmark that you see to the left of it

Comment: brother im new bee in developement , i don't understand alot  ... i just try to find a clear tutorial for understand it ... any idea to get a simple web server ?

Comment: @RouiniHo if you understand the majority of the code i posted feel free to ask questions about a few lines, but if you are completely lost, try using https://www.codecademy.com, also do keep in mind that a python web server has nothing specific to do with the pi so any python web server tutorial you find on google should work just fine

Comment: Mohammad thank you very much for your patient ... but yes i understand the codes ... i  try to do some tutorials in google .. i don't find a good one who work 100% .. im very sad about that

Comment: @RouiniHo what do you mean by "don't find a good one who works 100%"?

Comment: @MohammadAli You are really leading someone down the garden path in a bad way here.   What if the OP, e.g., suddenly realizes using web sockets would be good?  What about implementing AJAX exchanges? Etc.  This is great if what someone is interested in learning all about HTTP, which is fine (and: I've implemented an HTTP server from scratch -- it took me *three years* to complete properly) but an absurd distraction from the goal at hand.

Comment: @goldilocks i do know what you mean but considering the fact that he requested something "simple" and has little experience coding i believe http and HTML should be where he should start

Comment: Well, he's certainly going to have to learn all about HTML, and to a much lesser extent, some general conceptual things about HTTP (the "stateless" request-response cycle, the difference between GET and POST, etc.) but this is *not* the easy way; I'm sure python has piles of things to handle the gory details of parsing and creating protocol headers, etc.  I'm also sure they aren't hard to find w/ google...there are probably more tutorials than one person could read in a lifetime, lol.

Comment: @goldilocks I'm not saying he won't, I'm just trying to provide a simple answer which was requested in the question that meets the questions criteria to the best of my knowledge, so that i can get a few points on this site, and maybe one day become a moderator like you.

Comment: It is a decent introduction to what it's all about fundamentally.  RouiniHo has a bit of a hill to climb from here though.  You cannot take responsibility for that.  You'll be here for days.

Comment: @goldilocks yes, and thanks for the up vote, too bad moderators can't mark questions as answered eh, as all prospective employers seem to be looking at is the number of correct answers and points(personal experience).

Comment: thank you guys for the answers , now i get it with simple apache server and simple python script and i get the "hello world" on my browser ... Now one more think to do is to get values from pin . I do some research that tell me to install library GPIO any ideas ?

Comment: @RouiniHo well where are you receiving your data from? I recommend that you simply open it up as a new question as it is realitively unrelated to this one. Please leave link to the new question back here so I can take a good look at it

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/52095/get-data-from-gpio